# How to get better insights on slow-running SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlperformance

In certain periods, we are seeing slow queries on our SQL Server 2012 instance (on an Azure VM).

When analysing these queries (execution plan), there is nothing *obvious* wrong with the plan, and running them in management studio yields instant results.

My guess here is that there is lock contention issues.

My question is: how can i get better insights into why these queries are running slow?

Is there a third-party tool that's great for this job? (e.g Redgate SQL monitor)

From experience, the built-in SQL queries/tools that help diagnose these sorts of issues aren't very easy to use (manual queries, deadlock graphs, etc).

Can anyone point me in the right direction of either a great tool i can use, or a simple way within SQL Server to find out why they are running slow.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider checking Index fragmentation? On large databases, index fragmentation is like slow poisoning.

Comment: @ViKiNG yeah, you're right... indexes are horrible. 140+ indexes with > 30% fragmentation...top 10 are all above 90%. Still, kind of OT for this question.. i'd still like to know about tools that can help visualize this (I found out by running a manual SQL query). Any good articles you can point me to on how to defrag these indexes? (there's no many outdated ones on it). I'm on SQL Server 2012. Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking myself too :)

Comment: This is probably still the best? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes

Comment: Thanks @RPM1984.

Comment: No, thank you...i forgot about fragmentation... this is why i need a tool in the first place. Something more pro-active that _tells you_ when you need to do stuff. As opposed to fragmentation, which (unless you have a DBA/maintenance plan), only pops up when you have bad perf.

Comment: Have you see wait types? Wait type will also guide you for particular resource you are continuously waiting for.

Answer (score 1):

The best "free" tool that I've found is Blitz tools provide by Brent Ozar (part of first responder kit) found [here.](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/)

With these tools, you should be able to spot a problem very quickly, and sp_blitzindex will give all kinds of info on indexes.  You can automate/notify as you see fit.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29815033)